# How can I parse a JavaScript object with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the foreach equivalent in jQuery (JavaScript) to parse through a JSON object and return key/value pairs?

Comment: Put the question text in the question text, and make up a title that is just a title...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What do you mean by "JSON object"? JSON is a text format for serialising objects.

If you want to loop through the properties in an object that you got from deserialising a JSON string, you just loop through the property names:

```
for (key in object) {
  alert('key='+key+', value='+object[key]);
}
```

If you want to get the data from a JSON string, the easiest way is to parse it into an object. You can do that using an existing library, for example jQuery, or if you trust the contents of the string completely you can simply evaluate it:

```
var obj = eval(jsonString);
```