# Getting Nest structures as a list?

Tags: json, nest-api

I am struggling with the Nest API and its JSON response for structures. I would like a list of structure-objects, but instead Nest made multiple properties named the ID of the structure. To me it looks like that the one who implemented this, has completely misunderstood how to use JSON. I am hoping for at way to get the Nest API to return a more reasonable JSON structure. Is there any way to get a more list-friendly JSON repsonse from Nest. If so, how?

This is how Nest returns structures:

```
{
    "structures": {
        "VqFabWH21nwVyd4RWgJgNb292wa7hG_dUwo2i2SG7j3-BOLY0BA4sw": {
            "structure_id": "VqFabWH21nwVyd4RWgJgNb292wa7hG_dUwo2i2SG7j3-BOLY0BA4sw",
            "thermostats": [
                "peyiJNo0IldT2YlIVtYaGQ"
            ],
            "smoke_co_alarms": [
                "RTMTKxsQTCxzVcsySOHPxKoF4OyCifrs"
            ],
            "devices": {},
            "away": "home",
            "name": "Home",
            "country_code": "US",
            "postal_code": "94304",
            "peak_period_start_time": "2015-10-31T23:59:59.000Z",
            "peak_period_end_time": "2015-10-31T23:59:59.000Z",
            "time_zone": "America/Los_Angeles",
            "eta": {},
            "wheres": {
                "Fqp6wJI...": {
                    "where_id": "Fqp6wJI...",
                    "name": "Bedroom"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I would like to get instead:

```
{
    "structures": [
         {
            "structure_id": "VqFabWH21nwVyd4RWgJgNb292wa7hG_dUwo2i2SG7j3-BOLY0BA4sw",
            "thermostats": [
                "peyiJNo0IldT2YlIVtYaGQ"
            ],
            "smoke_co_alarms": [
                "RTMTKxsQTCxzVcsySOHPxKoF4OyCifrs"
            ],
            "devices": [],
            "away": "home",
            "name": "Home",
            "country_code": "US",
            "postal_code": "94304",
            "peak_period_start_time": "2015-10-31T23:59:59.000Z",
            "peak_period_end_time": "2015-10-31T23:59:59.000Z",
            "time_zone": "America/Los_Angeles",
            "eta": {},
            "wheres": [
                {
                    "where_id": "Fqp6wJI...",
                    "name": "Bedroom"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it, it's called an associative array. Has been asked before too, for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047460/how-to-loop-through-an-json-associative-array-in-javascript the details depend a bit on your programming environment

Comment: "There is nothing wrong with it". Maybe. But can you explain to me in which case it makes sense to use a associative array? In this case it is very clear that it is the exact same type of objects that are used and it makes sense for the data to be in a list. Why would anyone make an associative array instead of using a list?

Comment: @ThomasClemensen You can do O(1) look-ups on an object with a unique piece of identifying data that is not concerned with order (which the structure object is not). Carry around the id in your views and reconcile its details with a singular copy of the original object without having to iterate through an array or preserve order on the original data structure. Either way JSON is meant to express associative arrays via the object definition so its not "wrong" per se.

Comment: @CristianCavalli If you know the structure_id it makes sense, but in my case I have to find the structure_id in a strongly typed environment, it gives me a horrible work around. I cannot parse the data into predefined classes, because of the different property names. But let's just agree to disagree :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the JSON, what you see is called an [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), which is a form of collection, just like an array, list, or set. In JSON associative arrays can be expressed as an object `{}`. It's a pretty basic data structure known by many names, including Map or Dictionary depending on the programming language used.

Whether to use an associative array or an ordinary array/list depends largely on the way you want access the items. It doesn't have anything to do with the types of the objects stored in the collection.

Usually you would use an associative array if you want to access items by a key value and "normal" array/list if you want to access items by position. Also "normal" arrays/lists are usually better if the order of items is important, while associative arrays are usually not ordered (although they can be depending on implementation details).

Most programming environments allow you to iterate over a list of key values of an associative array, allowing similar access to "normal" array/list.

Here's a simple example in JavaScript:

```
var c;
c = [1, 2]; // ordinary array
c[0]; // access by position

var i;
for (i = 0; i < c.length; ++i) { // loop through all items and ...
    console.log(c[i]); // access by position
}

c = {"key1": 1, "key2": 2}; // associative array
c.key2; // access by key

var key;
for (key in c) { // iterate over all keys and ...
    console.log(c[key]); // access by key value
}
```